# add mouseclick event to panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, panel, mouseclick-event

I want to assign `mouseclick` event to `asp.net panel`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel p = new Panel();
    p.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);//but, this doesn't compiles correctly
}
protected void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     //C#code
}
```

Is there any way to add click event to panel?

Comment: There is no Click event for the panel in asp.net, you may try it wit Javascript see: http://forums.asp.net/t/1315282.aspx/1/10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what you can do to make your panel clickable and handle the event at server side.

Place panel in your web form

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="clickMe">
    Click here
</asp:Panel>
```

Add jQuery script library to your page.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" language="javascript"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Define the following client side event handler

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clickMe").click(function () {
        __doPostBack('clickMe', '');
    });
});
```

Handle the event at server side.

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(clickMe, "");
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] == "clickMe")
    {
        ClickMeOnClick();
    }
}
```

The code in PreRender event handler is for asp.net framework to render __doPostBack function at cilent sides. If your page includes a control that causes an auto postback you don't need this code.

Answer (score 1):

Mouseclick event with jQuery 1.7:

```
$('#placeholderID').on('click', '#panelID', function(e){ });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more easier solution, put a button before the panel closing tag, make, set the css style to cover the entire panel and opacity:0, adjust z-index to not cover your other elements, and just use your onclick method in code behind.

example:

css:

```
btn-panel{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

asp:

```
<asp:Panel ID="myPanel" runat="server" >

            //all your other elements here...
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="btn-panel"
                OnClick="YourButton_Click" />
</asp:Panel>
```

code behind:

```
protected void YourButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // Your Code Here...
    }
```

There you go, no javascript nor jquery for doing the magic!!

Answer (score 0):

Change the `asp:Panel` to an `asp:LinkButton` or wrap the panel in the LinkButton. This also prevents the `OnClick` from fighting with child control clicks, such as an `asp:CheckBox`.