# click event for a group of controls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've created a `user control` that has one `asp:Image` and one `asp:Label` below it and one more `asp:Label` below last label. I want this user control behaves like a button entirely, mean that we have a box that image and two labels are in it and when user click on every point on this box, it acts like a button and do anything according to it's click event.
can anyone please help me?

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="room.ascx.vb" Inherits="room" %>

<style type="text/css">
.image {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:2px;
    border:solid;
    border-width:1px;
}
.text {
    margin-left:2px;
    margin-right:2px;
    text-wrap:normal;
    text-align:right
}
</style>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel" runat="server" width="106px" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" BackColor="Wheat">
    <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" CssClass="image" /> <br />
    <asp:Label ID="name" runat="server" Text="name" Width="100px" CssClass="text" /> <br />
    <asp:Label ID="price" runat="server" Text="Label" Width="100px" CssClass="text" /> <br />
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: You can handle the client click event and then raise a postback manually. `__doPostBack('Panel','')`

Answer (score 0):

try adding  `onclick="yourFunction()"`  in asp:Panel so it will look like this

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel" runat="server" onClick="yourJsFunction()" width="106px" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" BackColor="Wheat">
    <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" CssClass="image" /> <br />
    <asp:Label ID="name" runat="server" Text="name" Width="100px" CssClass="text" /> <br />
    <asp:Label ID="price" runat="server" Text="Label" Width="100px" CssClass="text" /> <br />
</asp:Panel>
```

you can also check other questions on stackoverflow. Some already answered question can be found at following links

[add mouseclick event to panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739979/add-mouseclick-event-to-panel)

[Adding OnClick event to ASP.NET control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893409/adding-onclick-event-to-asp-net-control)